# Is there a way to add an Azure Active Directory Role to a Managed Identity using Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm deploying a function app using terraform and the function app has a system managed identity. My function app needs to be able to work with the directory, add users, create groups, add group members, etc... In the portal I can assign an active directory role to this managed identity and it works fine. I'd like to be able to do this programmatically. I've looked at the cli and powershell commands and there are commands to add roles to adusers, however these are just rbac roles, not directory roles. My thought was that I'd be able to do this with the graph API, however I've not yet been able to find a way to do this.

I'm able to connect to the graph api and the code below allows me to add a directory role to a user, but not a service principle. (My managed identity)

```
import requests

client_id = <client_id>
client_secret = <client_secret>

tokenPayload = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
}
r = requests.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant>/oauth2/token', data=tokenPayload)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'python_tutorial/1.0',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(r.json()['access_token']),
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
rolePayload = {
    '@odata.id': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/<id_of_my_managed_identity>'
}
servicePrinciples = requests.post(
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/<role_i_want_to_add_my_managed_identity_to>/members/$ref',
    json=rolePayload, headers=headers)
print(servicePrinciples.text)
```

I was expecting it to add the role to the managed identity, instead I get this message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Unsupported directory object class 'ServicePrincipal' specified by resource identifier.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "87ce7a2f-ebf7-402d-a987-c3823eee92f4",
      "date": "2019-08-23T04:21:24"
    }
  }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported in v1.0.

Please use beta version:

```
Post https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryRoles/<role_i_want_to_add_my_managed_identity_to>/members/$ref

body:
{
    '@odata.id': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/<id_of_my_managed_identity>'
}
```

Comment: I actually haven't tried adding directory roles to managed identity service principals. But this way should work, since you can add them to service principals in general. Hopefully these come out of beta soon :\